# How to define "minimum" distance Constraint in IOS for multiple UIVIews

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, constraints

Well i have 3 views like these:

[image: Three Views]

I need to define a Constraint so on either Blue or Mustard vertical resizing, the Red view will remain at minimum distance of either upper view, like

[image]

Or

[image]

So how can i achieve that result???

Comment: Can you just pin the distance between the red bar and the top of the view?

Comment: Nope... the fact is the upper views expand or collapse depending on pickers that appear there, so pining the red view will overlap the views...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Establish inequality vertical space constraints from both upper views to the red view:

- The vertical space from the mustard view to the red view is >= 8 points (or some other arbitrary space)
- The vertical space from the blue view to the red view is likewise >= 8 points

In addition, you may need a low-priority constraint that tries to keep the red view at the top of the superview, so that it doesn't pick some arbitrary point well below both views to occupy.